# How to set 100% width child of parent div

Tags: html, css, parent, children

I have the following grid layout. Overall I have more divs in grid layout but important are these **2 divs**:

[image]

**Div 3** is content of the page. That works fine. Layout is relatively good responsive. My issue is the side bar on the left side. I'd like set width of the side bar menu at 100% of **div 2** and also I'd like keep with same **width** of **sidebar** and **div 2**. Ofc **Sidebar** is inside of **Div 2**

For import sidebar to index I use web components

**index**

```
     <div id="div2">
        <aside>
          <sidebar></sidebar>
        </aside>
      </div>
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<div class="menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars vertical"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="side-bar">
      <section>
        <div class="close-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-times vertical"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="https://priklady.doucovanispetrem.cz/">
            <img
              src="#"
              alt="Logo" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <h1>Doučování</h1>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="item">
            <a class="sub-btn">
              Matice
              <i class="fas fa-angle-right dropdown"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="sub-menu">
              <a
                href="/pages/matice/zakladni-operace.html"
                id="matice/zakladni-operace"
                onClick="reply_click(this.id)"
                class="sub-item">
                Základní operace
              </a>
    ......
```

**Sidebar:**

```
.side-bar {
  background: #1b1a1b;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  width: 14.6%;
  min-width: 165px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  // left: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition-property: left;
}
```

**Grid:**

```
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 35.3% 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 16% 75.5% 8.5%;
  gap: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
}
#div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

#div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

#div4 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #grid {
    grid-template-columns: 20% 78% 2%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  #grid {
    grid-template-columns: 8.5% 83% 8.5%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue along with a clear description of the issue.

Comment: Hello, i've just updated my ask and added HTML

Answer (score 0):

Width in percentage is always according to parent. But in your case, .side-bar parent is .menu-btn which is then child of aside which is now child of div2.

So, what you want is make sure to have those 2 also be width:100%.

Also, from my point of view you shouldn't be using aside to hold your menu. nav is way better suited for this.

Comment: Hello, u were right but in my case was also necessary delete fixed position :)